# iOS Swift - How to wait end of request before return Info Window (Google Maps)

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, callback, infowindow

I am working with Google Maps and custom Info Window.

I have an issue where I need to update a label but the data comes from a success callback.

The problem here is that when the data is available I have already returned my Info Window and I can't update it anymore because it is already rendered (snapshot of the view).

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

    let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomInfoWindow

    let obs = marker.userData as! Observation

    ObsService.shared.getCityFromLatLong(lat: String(obs.coordinate.latitude), long: String(obs.coordinate.longitude)) { response in
       infoWindow.outletPlaceLabel.text = response
    }

    infoWindow.setDateAndTime(timestamp: obs.timestamp)

    return infoWindow
}
```

I know I have several options such as :

- Notification
- Wait until request is done (blocking UI?)
- Schedule my task
- Init method with logic instead of loadNibNamed only

I begin developing with Swift 3.

**EDIT:**  It's working with a sleep(2). But I CAN'T block the UI every time I need to display an info window.

I can't find an other solution.

Comment: get data for all coordinate before markerInfoWindow is called and store value in a array

Comment: So I have to make tons of request to the backend to potentially never use the data. Wouldn't it be better to only request it when needed (user tap on marker).

Comment: I don't know what thread getCityFromLatLong(lat:long:) calls back from - check in the debugger - but you may need to wrap "infoWindow.outletPlaceLabel.text = response" in an async call to the main thread. e.g. 
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    infoWindow.outletPlaceLabel.text = response
}

Comment: I already tried to wrap it in DispatchQueue.main. The real issue is the info window is already returned when the call is done. And I can't modify it when the window is rendered.

Comment: Hi Janna, if my answer worked for you, could you accept my answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cityName: String?

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    if cityName == nil {
        let obs = marker.userData as! Observation
        ObsService.shared.getCityFromLatLong(lat: String(obs.coordinate.latitude), long: String(obs.coordinate.longitude) { response in
            self.cityName = response
            // Replace the existing map view with a new one here. Or call it's refresh function if it has one (I don't know, haven't used Google map view)
            return
        }
    }
    return self.mapViewHelper(mapView, markerInfoWindow: marker, city: cityName ?? "")
}

func mapViewHelper(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker, city: String?) -> UIView? {
    let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomInfoWindow
    let obs = marker.userData as! Observation

    infoWindow.outletPlaceLabel.text = response
    infoWindow.setDateAndTime(timestamp: obs.timestamp)

    return infoWindow
}
```

If you have set the map view initially using Interface builder, you can give it a tag, and then search for the view with the relevant tag, instantiate a new map view where I have written the comment, and replace the existing map view (copying its frame from the existing map view). The map view may also have a refresh function you can call. See the documentation for views for how to search for views with tags (sorry if that's teaching a grandmother to suck eggs!)

Comment: BTW, again, I would check the thread getCityFromLatLong(lat:long:) in case you need to wrap in DispatchQueue.main.async {  }

Comment: This is brillant, but I don't understand your 2 comments. And where should I call displayMapView ? I need to display the info window thank to the delegate method markerInfoWindow, which return an info window.

Comment: OK. Is the function  "mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView?" a delegate callback, or do you call that function yourself? If it's a delegate callback, then I need to have more context for how mapView(_:markerInfoWindow:) gets called to be able to help you. If you call the function yourself, presumably you are doing something with the view it returns.

Comment: it's the GoogleMaps delegate method, it get called when a marker is tapped ( when the mapView need to render the info window).

Comment: Note the code in place of my comment "// However you triggered the request for a google mapview here" must be in addition to the code used to trigger its display the first time.

Comment: Humm.. I never request google mapview, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean you do something at some point to trigger the display of the map view so the google library calls the delegate callback  "func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView?"

Comment: Maybe you are just setting the map view in the Interface Builder, in which case you will need to work out how to instantiate it and replace the existing map view with a new one programmatically (updated the comment in the answer slightly to reflect this)

Comment: Yes I call mapView.setSelectedMarker, it will display the info window of the selected marker

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let infoWindow:CustomInfoWindow? // declare out side of method
```

**Your function Now**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

     infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomInfoWindow

    let obs = marker.userData as! Observation

    ObsService.shared.getCityFromLatLong(lat: String(obs.coordinate.latitude), long: String(obs.coordinate.longitude)) { response in
       infoWindow.outletPlaceLabel.text = response
    }

    infoWindow.setDateAndTime(timestamp: obs.timestamp)

    return infoWindow
}
```

Comment: This won't make any difference because it is logically identical to the example code in the question, since the reference to Info window is in both cases under the hood a pointer to the same object.